# Where is Xcode Project in React Native?

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I am trying to find my Xcode project file inside React Native so I can setup React Native Firebase (https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios)

However, I cannot find where the Xcode project file is? Can anyone help.

Comment: I'm not sure if it works but did you search your project in spotlight?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find Xcode project files here:

```
yourProjectDir/ios/yourprojectname.xcodeproj
```

If You use cocoapods then you should always use this file:

```
yourProjectDir/ios/yourprojectname.xcworkspace
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an iOS folder, I used the createapp method?

Comment: If You used expo then you need to eject your app. Read more here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject

Comment: create-react-native-app is now EXPO and You need to eject app to work with native code.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Expo or create react native app you will not have an iOS folder as these are abstracted away from you.

If you wish to use a dependency that requires you to edit native code then you need to eject your application. https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject

From your command line run `expo eject` and it will build the necessary ios and android folders for you. However there are several ramifications if you eject your app. You should read the above link carefully.

Answer (score 0):

`YourRNProject/ios` and there you have it inside!

Answer (score 0):

Open your react native folder

you can see **ios** folder

this folder is what you search for

Comment: Doesn't seem to have an iOS folder, I used the createapp method?

Comment: @ManJames I understand your issue , you use expo for your project

Comment: @ManJames you must use native way of creating project

Comment: @ManJames goto https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started and read docs on **Build projects with native code**

Comment: @ManJames Or you can eject your expo project but first read documentation and prepare your system for native development **Android Studio and Xcode**

Comment: @MohammadAnsari I searched this documentation but the part with iOS project is just skipped. Your answer is reported as unfriendly